# Reordenar ID incremental en JavaScript después de eliminar una fila de la tabla no sigue el orden del correlativo

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mvc

Tengo un modal donde paso los productos una tabla detalle cotizacion al pasar cada producto del modal a la tabla genera un ID incremental que es la 1ra columna de la tabla.

Vemos en la 1ra imagen el modal pasa productos a la tabla y en la 1ra columna vemos que hemos pasado 7 productos generando los IDs 1,2,3,4,5,6 y 7 hasta ahi todo bien pero el inconveniente es cuando le doy clic en el boton eliminar me elimina las filas pero despues no las ordena de manera correlativa.

Es decir despues de eliminar los prodcutos en este caso he eliminado 3 productos como muestra la 2da Imagen solo nos muestra los IDs 1,3,5 y 7 deberia de mostrar en orden los IDs asi: 1,2,3 y 4.

He intentado de muchas maneras pero no logro resolver el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La 2da Imagen solo hay 4 IDs y deberia despues de eliminar ordenar los IDs quedando 1,2,3 y 4.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<script>
 //-- Función agregar productos -- Aqui paso los productos del modal al tabla cotización.
 var artite = 0; var artimp = 0;
 $(document).on("click", ".agrpro", function () {
     row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
     artite = artite + 1;
         artcod = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); 
     var artmod = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
     var artdes = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
     var artmar = row.find("td:eq(3)").text();
     var artpsi = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
     var artpci = row.find("td:eq(5)").text();
     var artsto = row.find("td:eq(8)").text(); //-- Stock
     var artcan = $("#cantAdd_" + artcod).val();        
     var total = parseFloat((artcan * artpsi).toFixed(2));
     var artplb = row.find("td:eq(6)").text();
     var totlib = parseFloat((artcan * artplb).toFixed(2));
     var artpkg = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(7)").text());
     var totklg = parseFloat((artcan * artpkg).toFixed(2));
     /*var cotimp = (artcan - artsto)*/

     if (artcan > artsto) {
         artimp = cotimp ;
     } else {
         artimp = 0;
     }

     var contbod =
            `<tr class="table-responsive-sm">
             <td class='text-center cotite'>${artite}</td>
             <td class='text-center'>${artcod}</td>
             <td>${artmod}</td>
             <td>${artdes}</td>
             <td>${artmar}</td>
             <td>${artpsi}</td>
             <td>${artpci}</td>
             <td>${artsto}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class="cotcan">${artcan}</td>
             <td>${artimp}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class='subtotal'>${total}</td>
             <td>${artplb}</td>
             <td class="cottlb">${totlib}</td>
             <td>${artpkg}</td>
             <td  class="cottkg">${totklg}</td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="btn_remove btn btn-xs btn-danger ml-1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>Eliminar</button></td>
             </tr>`;
     $("#tabCot tbody").append(contbod);
/*     document.getElementById("TxtSer").value = final;*/
    /* $('#tabCot').dataTable();*/
     calsum()
     elifil()
 })
 
 //-- Función eliminar productos
 function elifil() {
    $("body").on("click", ".btn_remove", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        calsum()
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hay un problema de lógica acá. Una cosa es el id incremental de una base de datos, y otra un id representativo para el usuario. Si quieres mostrar el ID real de una tabla, este es es fijo, no debe ni debería cambiar. Ahora, si solo quieres listar los elementos de una tabla, bastaría con contar cuantos elementos hay en esta, y asignar ese valor a la fila correspondiente.

Comment: Hola Excorpion, son IDs o ítems que cuando voy agregando un producto del modal que es la 1ra imagen, a la tabla que es la 2da imagen va agregando los IDs que es la 1ra columna de la tabla y lo hago de esta manera: artite = artite + 1; el inconvenientes es cuando elimino lo debe refrescar y colocar en orden, ejemplo si tengo 3 productos en la tabla que son los IDs 1,2 y 3 y elimino el ID 2 debería de refrescar y mostrar los IDs 1,2 es decir debe tomar el IDs de manera ordenada y secuencial. Estos IDs no son traídos de la Base de Datos, después de resolver el problema serán grabados a la BD.

Comment: @WillianEdgarEvangelioAvila, al eliminar la fila simplemente tendrías que reenumerar las filas. Buscas en `tbody` todos los `tr` y en cada uno buscar el `td.cotite` y poner el número según el orden en el que están. PD: para responder a un comentario de un usuario en especial, tenes que usar `@[NOMBRE]`, sino el usuario no se entera que has respondido a su comentario.

Comment: @Marcos, gracias por las recomendaciones y las indicaciones voy ha probar y te comento como me va.

Answer (score 0):

No estas guardando los objetos en javascript (por ejemplo, en un array), por lo que deduzco que al momento de enviar lo datos al servidor lees toda la tabla, lo cual hace que esos "id" autoincrementables sean cosméticos y por ende es posible usar CSS.

La idea es usar el [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) de CSS para mostrar los números, el cual con la configuración básica nos dará el correlativo que buscamos. Esto es solo para mostrar los números al usuario. Finalmente, para enviarlos, al leero los datos crear el correlativo final y lo envías.

Un ejemplo:

```js
function GetFaKeName() {
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  
  const largo = getRandomInt(4, 10);
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(getRandomInt(97, 122));
  }
  return result;
}


function agregar() {
  document
    .querySelector("#tabCot tbody")
    .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
      `<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>${GetFaKeName()}</td>
      <td><button onclick="remove(this)">Quitar</button></td>
    </tr>`);
}

function remove(element){
  element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

function leer(){
  let filas = document.querySelectorAll("#tabCot tbody tr");
  let datos = [];
  
  filas.forEach( (item,i) =>{
    let celdas = Array.from(item.querySelectorAll("td"));
    datos.push({
      cod: i+1,
      nombre: celdas[1].innerText
    });
  });
  
  console.log(datos);
}
```

```css
tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr td:first-child:before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
<button onclick="leer()">Leer</button>
<table id="tabCot">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cod</th>
      <th>Un Nombre</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="datos">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td><button onclick="remove(this)">Quitar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Todas las funciones de javascript son a modo de ejemplo y no son relevante para tu pregunta. Lo único que te interesa es la parte CSS.

Comment: Hola @Yussef, gracias por las indicaciones y recomendaciones respondiendo lo que mencionas líneas arriba, es correcto lo que indicas envió lo datos del modal a la tabla, en ese proceso mando los "id" autoincrementadles con esta linea de código:  artite = artite + 1; Gracias por mencionar la función del CSS. [Counter] no lo había escuchado, el detalle es que he probado y afecta a todas mis tablas que se encuentran alojados en ese Form. Voy ha intentar ajustar el estilo indicado para que solo afecte a la tabla = tabCot, que es lo que necesito. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Yussef,  te comento como me va con el ejemplo que mencionas gracias por tu ayuda.